# Raspberry PI, 1 LED with 2 buttons

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi, gpio, led

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode( GPIO.BCM )
GPIO.setwarnings( 0 )

print( "input copy" )

led = 18
switch_1 = 23
switch_2 = 24

GPIO.setup( led, GPIO.OUT )
GPIO.setup( switch_1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN )
GPIO.setup( switch_2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN )
while True:
   if( GPIO.input( switch_1 ) ):
      GPIO.output( led, GPIO.LOW )
   if (GPIO.input(switch_2)):
       GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Hi everyone, I have 1 LED and 2 buttons. I want one button to turn the LED on, and the other button to turn it off again. My code can only do one of these two actions. Any help is welcome on how to get this to work.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, not getting an error. However, when I push the button to turn the LED off simply nothing happens.

Comment: Have you checked the gpio connections?

Comment: Is your user on the `gpio` group?: `sudo usermod -a -G gpio <username>`

Comment: @Joac embarrassed to say it was indeed just the setup of my wires. All fixed now!